# Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test when the target method has 2 api calls

Tags: angularjs, jestjs

I am facing an issue for Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a particular test. below is the method that I am testing:

```
createTask(
    newTask: TaskModel,
    status: string
  ): Observable<Model> {
    let status: String;
    if ('Publish' === publishStatus) {
      status = 'Published';
    } else {
      status = 'Draft';
    }
    return this.http
      .post<void>(
        `${this.envTasksApi}/tasks`,
        {
          ...newTask,
          currentStatus: status,
        },
        {
          headers: this.headers,
        }
      )
      .pipe(
        tap(() => {
          this.store.add(task);
        }),
        switchMap(() => {
          return this.publishTaskAction(newTask, publishStatus);
        })
      );
  }
```

below is my test class code:

```
it('should be created', (done) => {
    jest.spyOn(store, 'addTask');
    taskApiService.createTask(taskToStore[0], 'Publish').subscribe((taskHistoryModel) => {
      expect(store.addTask).lastCalledWith(taskToStore[0]);
      done();
    });
    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(api + '/tasks');
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
    expect(req.request.body).toEqual({
      ...taskToStore[0],
      currentStatus: 'Published',
    });
    req.flush(taskToStore[0]);
  });
```

If I remove the switchMap part from the method to be tested, then the tests are running fine. Please suggest any way to fix this. Thanks!!

Edit1: As suggested by Esaith, I updated the code below:

```
it('should save task in store when new one is created', (done) => {
    jest.spyOn(store, 'addTask');
    taskApiService.createTask(taskToStore[0], 'Publish').subscribe(() => {
      taskApiService.publishActionTask(taskToStore[0], 'Publish').subscribe(() => {
        expect(store.addTask).lastCalledWith(taskToStore[0]);
      });
      const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(api + '/tasks');
      expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
      expect(req.request.body).toEqual({
        ...taskToStore[0],
        currentStatus: 'Published',
      });
      req.flush(taskToStore[0]);
      done();
    });
  });
```

Still facing the same issue.

Edit2: I wrote a separate test for publishActionTask and there as well timeout is happening. Below is the code:

```
it('should publish the task', (done) => {
    jest.spyOn(store, 'addTask');
    jest.setTimeout(30000);
    taskApiService.publishActionTask(taskToStore[0], 'PublishTask').subscribe(() => {
      const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(api + '/tasks/actions');
      expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
      req.flush(taskToStore[0]);
      done();
    });
  });
```

Although this code is working well when tested through web. Any more suggestions please.

Comment: you could try to increase test timeout see if that helps. maybe it just takes a bit

Comment: I added jest.setTimeout(30000); to the first line after it(), but still the same error.

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't be making real API calls in a test. Even if you had a max of 3s per test but had a 1000 tests, thats just a few minutes getting coffee while waiting for your tests to finish. I would expect the req and last 2 expect-functions to be within the subscribe function before the done() is called.

Comment: @Esaith, I edited the question with the code. Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: What does publishTaskAction do? Is that an observable that returns within a satisfactory time?

Comment: I again edited the question with the new test code for publishTaskAction. Getting timeout error there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well the error message mislead me, when writing the test case, expects should be done in order of the calls done from main code. So this is what worked for me:

```
it('should save task in store when new one is created', (done) => {
    jest.spyOn(store, 'addSomething1');
    taskApiService.createTask(taskToStore[0], 'action1').subscribe(() => {
      expect(store.addTask).lastCalledWith(taskToStore[0]);
      done();
    });

    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('mock-task-path' + '/tasks');
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
    req.flush(null);
    const publishReq = httpTestingController.expectOne(
      'mock-task-path' + '/tasks/actions'
    );
    expect(publishReq.request.method).toEqual('POST');
    publishReq.flush(null);
    const getHistoryReq = httpTestingController.expectOne(
      'mock-task-path' + '/tasks/Finance/test1/history'
    );
    expect(getHistoryReq.request.method).toEqual('GET');
    getHistoryReq.flush({
      taskId: '1',
      taskStatuses: [
        {
          id: null,
          date: null,
          status: 'Action1',
          changes: '',
        },
      ],
    });
  });
```